# How to calculate the position of Item of Fram in iPhone ?

Tags: iphone, ios

First, I have an item that I draw with UIView . I want to draw the 20 items that one row has 4 items so  there is 5 rows.My question is how can I find or calculate all positions of Item.

Comment: By using elementary math, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an iPhone:

```
const float itemWidth = 320.0 / 4;
const float itemHeight = 480.0 / 4;

for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
    {
        CGRect frm = CGRectMake(col * itemWidth, row * itemHeight, itemWidth, itemHeight);
        // frm contains the position and size of each element
    }
```

Needs adjustment for iPad or if you want padding between the elements.